# Aws data recovery if data got deleted using rm -r command

Tags: ubuntu, backup, amazon-web-services

I have an ubuntu server on AWS. And accidentally some data got deleted with rm -r command.

Now the situation is that i don't have any service plan for backup.

Do Aws have my previous backup or if i buy the service plan for backup then would i get my previous backup also

Answer (score 0):

No. AWS cannot recover it. If you delete files and do not have a backup, they are lost.